# Specify dispatch queue on iOS

Tags: ios, inheritance, swift

Using **Swift**, I have a custom class that wraps the `CBCentralManager` class as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

protocol vaBeanDelegate
{

}

class vaBean: CBCentralManager, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

override init() {
    println("bean manager initialised")
    super.init()
    self.delegate = self
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    println("discovered peripheral(s)")
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state) {
    case .PoweredOff:
        println("hardware is powered off")

    case .PoweredOn:
        println("hardware is powered on and ready")
        //centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    case .Resetting:
        println("hardware is resetting")

    case .Unauthorized:
        println("state is unauthorized")

    case .Unknown:
        println("state is unknown");

    case .Unsupported:
        println("hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
    println("didConnectPeripheral")
}

func searchForNewBeans() {
    println("searching for new beans...")
    self.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}
}
```

The class initialises and I can then call the `searchForNewBeans` function, but I don't receive any responses from the `didUpdateState` or `didDiscoverPeripheral` functions. I suspect it's because my new class doesn't know it should be the receiver for these, but how and where would I specify that? My calling code in my `ViewController` is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var myBean: vaBean!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("blueToothTest v1.00")
    println("opening bluetooth connection ...")
    myBean = vaBean()
    myBean.searchForNewBeans()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}
}
```

My log is as follows when I execute currently:

**blueToothTest v1.00**

opening bluetooth connection ...

bean manager initialised

searching for new beans...

Answer (score 2):

I think your first problem is that you aren't calling the designated initialiser for CBCentralManager.

Also, You can't call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` until you are in the `PoweredOn` state.

The way your current code is written you will undoubtedly call `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` before this state.

I would suggest something like the following:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

protocol vaBeanDelegate
{

}

class vaBean: CBCentralManager, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

var isScanning=false
var isPowered=false

 override init() {

    println("bean manager initialised")
    super.init(delegate: nil, queue: nil, options:[NSObject : AnyObject]())   //Initialise with self as the delegate and default queue
    self.delegate=self

}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    println("discovered peripheral(s)")
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {
    switch (central.state) {
    case .PoweredOff:
        println("hardware is powered off")

    case .PoweredOn:
        println("hardware is powered on and ready")
        self.isPowered=true
        if (self.isScanning) {
           self.searchForNewBeans()
        }
        //centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    case .Resetting:
        println("hardware is resetting")

    case .Unauthorized:
        println("state is unauthorized")

    case .Unknown:
        println("state is unknown");

    case .Unsupported:
        println("hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!) {
    println("didConnectPeripheral")
}

func searchForNewBeans() {
    self.isScanning=true;
    if (self.isPowered) {
        println("searching for new beans...")
        self.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: +1. Also, to answer the OP's question about the dispatch queue - the code leaves this as `nil`, which "dispatches central role events using the main queue" according to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Even if I implement the designated initialiser my problem is that none of the functions are being called. The code change above makes sense, but centralManagerDidUpdateState isn't being called once the class is initialised.

Comment: Within 'init()' the line 'self.init(delegate:self,queue:nil)' gives an error of "Use of 'self' in delegating initializer before self.init is called". I'm more confused now.

Comment: I wasn't sure about that - Let me try it in XCode and update my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer to call the correct superclass initialiser and my test discovered peripherals